# The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded

Tags: mono

I wanted to run my software on a VPS, however, when I try to run it with mono, it says

```
The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.It should have been installed in the '/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll' directory.
```

I've already tried to install mono-complete

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

However, it says mono-complete is already the newest version.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Sincerely,
Mike

(  I run on my VPS on ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, and my mono version is 4.0.0)

Comment: Have you tried building mono manually? http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git

Answer (score 2):

I came across the problem last day.You need to install `mono-2.0` to execute certain programs.

To install mono 2.0 ,open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install libmono2.0-cil
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, it didn't work though, it's already the newest version

Comment: @mike version **2.0 is different than 4.0** .They can  be both installed at same time.If the command doesn't work, try software center.

Comment: I probably explained the it the wrong way, when I executed the command, it says it couldn't install because it was already the latest version

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libmono-system2.0-cil`

Comment: Also already the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my brother's computer. It seems to be an installation problem. MonoDevelop thinks mono's libraries are installed in /usr/local/lib/... I couldn't fix that problem, so I symlinked /usr/lib/mono in /usr/local/lib

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mono /usr/local/lib/mono
```

That works for now, but that isn't the solution. Does anyone know how to tell MonoDevelop where to look for the libraries? without having to build/install it manually.

Comment: You could use a symlink instead of copying.

Comment: Yes, it's better :) I did that after. And also, I set MONO_PATH correctly.